# change position of sidebar in shinydashboard R

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to change the sidebar of my dashboard from left (shiny dashboard default) to the right side of the page, but I can not. please HELP...
here is a sample code(for your convenience, I have changed the color of the two parts which I want to move to the right side of the page):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                                  .skin-blue .main-header .logo {

                                          background-color: #000000;
                                          }

                                          /* main sidebar */
                                          .skin-blue .main-sidebar {

                                          background-color: #ef43ad;
                                          }'))))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but I doubt it can be done. shinydashboard is based on AdminLTE theme and as you can see in this github issue https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/1497 it seems like is not possible to move the sidebar without using a different fork of the theme